# Using parameters with a spring @Scheduled expression

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cron

I'm trying to paramaterize a cron expression currently used for a Spring @Scheduled expression.
All other variables coming from the client configuration seem to be loaded correctly for other variables, but Spring doesn't seem to be able to pick up anything in the cron expression.

I've tried a variety of different ways of doing it but none seem to work. Throwing errors like

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Encountered invalid @Scheduled method 'importData': Could not resolve placeholder 'cronExpression' in value "${cronExpression}"
```

I've tried calling the expression directly from the config file

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
    public void importData() {
```

using the @Qualifier and giving it a direct string name

```
@Qualifier("cronExpression") String cronExpression
this.cronExpression = cronExpression
...
@Scheduled(cron = "${cronExpression}")
    public void importData() {
```

but these all still return the above error message

In the client config class, I'm currently trying to import the variable like this:

```
    @Bean
    @Qualifier("cronExpression")
    public String cronExpression(@Value("${my.cron.expression}") String cronExpression) {
        return cronExpression;
    }
```

Aside from names, this is the code I'm using which is still throwing an unresolved placeholder error:
Properties:

```
my:
  cron:
    expression: 0 0 4-6 * * *
```

ClientConfig:

```
    @Qualifier("cronExpression")
    public String cronExpression(@Value("${my.cron.expression}") String cronExpression) {
        return cronExpression;
    }
```

Scheduler:

```
private final String cronExpression;
...
@Qualifier("cronExpression") String cronExpression
...
this.cronExpression = cronExpression
...
@Scheduled(cron = "${cronExpression}")
```

Comment: What is the actual value of the my.cron.expression? I assume it is somewhere in your props?

Comment: This @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}") must work.

Comment: Hi both, the cron expression is configured in the properties file as : "my.cron.expression":"0 0 4-8 * * *"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my Spring Java class:

```java
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@Slf4j
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Scheduled(cron = "${my.cron.expression}")
    public void test(){
        log.info("hello!");
    }
}
```

And here's my *application.yml* configuration file:

```yaml
my.cron.expression: 0 */1 * * * ?
```

With this configuration, my log is triggered every minute.
(I haven't added particular dependencies)

---

#### NOTE

Be careful with the String wrapping of your property: try to **unquote** it, if Spring gives you an error.

Comment: Hi Paolo, thank you, I'll try using having the cron expression with no quotes. The properties are hosted on a config server, and resolved in a ClientConfig class, like this: ```@Bean
@Qualifier("cronExpression")
public String articleMetadataCronExpression(@Value("${my.cron.expression}") String cronExpression) {
        return cronExpression;
    }```
Do you think that changes how I need to tackle this?

Comment: Hello. Unfortunately, @ Scheduled annotation is such a lot limited...it requires a constant (in fact, even using @ Value annotation, provided by Spring, doesn't work since it works with reflection and class instances, which is not what we are talking about). The only thing you can put is a String (constant) or an application property that Spring itself tries to resolve. We hope that they could enlarge its current working with some new feature, or you will have to use your own custom scheduler.